# jenkins fatal: ambiguous argument, unknown revision or path not in the working tree

Tags: jenkins, git

In jenkins pipeline, execute git command :

```
git log --format=%B --no-merges origin/master..origin/${currentBranch}
```

jenkins output error :

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master..origin/XOPS-42_AddResultToJIRA': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

but in my local computer i execute above git command, it work well, how to resolve above error in jenkins

Comment: Does branch `XOPS-42_AddResultToJIRA` exist? How is `currentBranch` set?

Answer (score 1):

From the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) around the command `git rev-list`:

**`git rev-list A...B`**

Try your command syntax like the above (i.e. `origin/master...origin/${currentBranch}`)